# Включить на сервере для socket.io потдержку EIO=3

Tags: node.js, socket.io

## Используемые модули

- Node.js
- express
- socket.io

Я хочу сделать сервер на Node.js с webSocket соединением.
Использовать npm пакет web socket я не могу потому что на стороне клиента используется socket.io.

*На стороне сервера я подключил библиотеку*

```
    let app = express();
    app.use(express.json())
    app.use(cors({ credentials: true }));
    let server = http.createServer(app);
    const io = new Server(server);

    io.on('connection', (socket) => {
        console.log('a user connected');
    });
```

*На стороне клиента подключение тоже работает в таком виде.*

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
const socket = io("ws://127.0.0.1:8010");
```

Но с клиента который мне требуется запрос на подключение выглядит следующим образом

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
const socket = io("ws://127.0.0.1:8010/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket");
```

В документации я нашёл параметр *allowEIO3: true* но он не срабатывает.

Comment: у вас есть код в котором веб-сокет подключается  на `ws://127.0.0.1:8010` и подключается на `127.0.0.1:8010/socket.io`. какая точка подключения должна быть на самом деле?

Comment: socket.io это значение по default по этому эта запись правильная.
Я не знаю почему, скорее всего запись в строку не валидная, Но я поставил  transports:'websocket', allowEIO3:true и клиент подключился успешно.

Comment: закрывайте вопрос, если проблема больше не актуальны

Comment: У меня клиент заработал, но почему в приведённом формате не работает ответа нет. По идее работать должно. Время будет, хочу разобраться с этим. Я представляю из за чего это может быть но надо смотреть.